# how to send Facebook notification to specific friend in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am able to fetch my friends in grid. now on selection some specific friend I want to send notification. I am doing something like this:

```
foreach(GridViewRow gvrow in gvFriends.Rows) 
{
    CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox) gvrow.FindControl("chkselect");
    if (chkdelete.Checked) 
    {
        usrid = Convert.ToInt64(gvFriends.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value);
        Dictionary < string, string > data = new Dictionary < string, string > ();
        data.Add("link", "http://localhost:51067/FacebookTestApp/FacebookUsers.aspx");
        data.Add("picture", "http://localhost:52591/facebook_notification/Koala.jpg");
        data.Add("caption", "invitation");
        data.Add("name", "App invitation");
        data.Add("message", "you are invited for app");
        FaceBookConnect.Post(ViewState["Code"].ToString(), "me/feed", data);
    }
}
```

it is not showing any error but when my friend checked his account he did not get any notification.
I want to send notification to them and clicking on notification they should redirect to my asp page....

Comment: Still looking for any kind of suggestion or reply...........

Comment: Did you found some answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "[Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/)" you can use the *SendNotification* function.